# How can i speed up hexadecimal characters conversion to binary characters

Tags: c, hex, data-conversion

I have already a function that convert hex char(input) to binary char(output). it works perfect, for small amount of data(input length).But when the input is too big, it stuck/not working. May be **strcat** take too much time. Is there some alternate solution, So i can convert big hex input characters into equivalent binary.
My function is:

```
void fun_hex_ch_2bin(int len_hex_str,uint8_t *hex,uint8_t *bin){
  /* Extract first digit and find binary of each hex digit */
  int i=0,j=0;

   char array_hex[16]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
   uint8_t *new_hex=malloc(len_hex_str*2);
   char hex_char1,hex_char2;
   j=0;
   for(i=0;i<len_hex_str;i++)
   {
      hex_char1=array_hex[hex[i]&0x0f];
      hex_char2=array_hex[(hex[i]>>4)&0x0f];
      //printf("%c  %c\n",hex_char1,hex_char2);
      new_hex[j]=hex_char2;
      new_hex[j+1]=hex_char1;
      j=j+2;
   }

    for(i=0; i<len_hex_str*2; i++)
    {
        switch(new_hex[i])
        {
            case '0':
                strcat(bin, "0000");
                break;
            case '1':
                strcat(bin, "0001");
                break;
            case '2':
                strcat(bin, "0010");
                break;
            case '3':
                strcat(bin, "0011");
                break;
            case '4':
                strcat(bin, "0100");
                break;
            case '5':
                strcat(bin, "0101");
                break;
            case '6':
                strcat(bin, "0110");
                break;
            case '7':
                strcat(bin, "0111");
                break;
            case '8':
                strcat(bin, "1000");
                break;
            case '9':
                strcat(bin, "1001");
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                strcat(bin, "1010");
                break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                strcat(bin, "1011");
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                strcat(bin, "1100");
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                strcat(bin, "1101");
                break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
                strcat(bin, "1110");
                break;
            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                strcat(bin, "1111");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid hexadecimal input.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `strcat` takes `char*` not `uint8_t*` Why do you first convert to hex then convert to binary? Why not convert to binary in the first loop? You leak memory from `new_hex = malloc`, you never free it. And you have two loops, which makes it very slow, and you have `malloc` call, which makes it slow. For starters, remove the first loop and remove the malloc call. Then replace the `switch` with lookup table Also you function is very unsafe, it's easy to overflow the `bin` buffer with those `strcat` calls. Add `size_t binsize` parameter and replace `strcat` with `strlcat`

Comment: You're using the [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sprintf()` instead of `strcat()`

```
char *bin; // points to a long enough buffer
int binlen = 0;
binlen += sprintf(bin + binlen, "something"); // strcat(bin, "something");
binlen += sprintf(bin + binlen, "otherthing"); // strcat(bin, "otherthing");
binlen += sprintf(bin + binlen, "foobar"); // strcat(bin, "foobar");
//...
// you can even do
binlen += sprintf(bin + binlen, "%.2f", 2.71828); // strcat(bin, "2.72");
```

Answer (score 1):

16 is a power of 2 so converting it to binary is pretty simple.
Each hex digit corresponds to exactly 4 binary digits - and you can rely on this fact.
As a first step you need to convert the input characters from ASCII to numeric values.
That's easily done in one pass over the input hex string and subtracting 48 if the character is between `'0'` and `'9'` or subtracting 88 if the character is between `'a'` and `'f'` (take a look at the ASCII table if need an explanation on why).
After that the conversion is straightforward - go over the hex array and for each hex value take a look at the last bit and proceed to the next bit exactly 4 times, move to the next hex value and repeat the procedure. 
Something like this:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
while(i < len_hex_str)
{
   bin[j++]=hex[i] & 1;
   hex[i] >>= 1;
   if(j % 4 == 0) i++;
}
```

And since you seem to be in need to have it ASCII representation, just pass over the output string and add 48 to each digit.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i speed up hexadecimal characters conversion to binary characters (?)
>   May be strcat take too much time.

Yes.  Each call to `strcat()` takes longer and longer time as code does not take advantage of data already converted.

`strcat()` take `n` time to traverse the first characters.

```
1st strcat call, n = 0    
2st strcat call, n = 8    
3rd strcat call, n = 16    
4th strcat call, n = 24
ith strcat call, n = 8*(i-1)
```

See how the sum (0+8+16+24+...) goes up by order of `i*i` as `i` increases?

---

Note that the first call to `strcat(bin, ...)` is suspect as `bin[0]` is not certainly a null character - something required when concatenating to a *string*.

---

> Is there some alternate solution (?)

I recommend a re-write.  Directly read from `hex` as binary and skip the in-between conversion to hexadecimal.

```
void fun_hex_ch_2bin(int len_hex_str, uint8_t *hex, uint8_t *bin) {
  while (len_hex_str > 0) {
    len_hex_str--;
    // Start with the MSBit
    for (uint8_t mask = 0x80; mask; mask >>=1) {
      *bin++ = mask & *hex ? '1' : '0';
    }
    hex++;
  }
  // Append a null character as `bin` is to point to a _string_.
  *bin = '\0';
}
```

---

I'd expect `bin`, as a *string* to be `char*` and not `unit8_t *`.

Comment: Your mask should be `0x8` rather than `0x80` and you need to convert the ASCII input to a valid hex before bit manipulations.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername OP's `hex` is an 8 bit pattern.  OP's unnecessarily changes that byte to 2 hex characters and then to binary.  This answers omits the middle unnecessary step and converts 8-bit binary directly to 8 `'0'/'1'` characters.  OP's input `hex` does not point to ASCII data.

Comment: I'm not talking about OP's implementation, it's obviously suboptimal. I'm referring to your usage of 8-bit mask on ASCII data to yield binary output. It's incorrect - you need to first convert the ASCII input to numeric and after that produce the binary output with 4-bit mask and not 8-bit mask because each hex digit corresponds to exactly 4 binary bits.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername OP's code has `hex_char1=array_hex[hex[i]&0x0f];
      hex_char2=array_hex[(hex[i]>>4)&0x0f];`.  That is taking each byte of `hex[i]` and converting to 2 hex characters.  `hex[]` is not ASCII input - it is binary.  This answer's mask is on that binary data pointed to by `hex`.

Comment: You keep addressing OP's code. It can be optimized in many ways but it's not the issue here. You completely reimplemented his function so I don't see how and why you relate to some irrelevant piece of code in his original answer. Moreover, it contradicts what you said yourself: "I recommend a re-write directly to binary and skip the in-between conversion to hexadecimal".